# coredata problem nsurl may not respond to stringByAppendingPathComponent

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsurl

I had some problems after starting a new coredata project with the xcode 3.2.5... my previous projects with core data (in previous xcode) worked fine, so I dont know what is the difference??

so the error I get when I build and go to the view that calls the core data is>

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: '***  -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter'
```

the strange thing is that in my *AppDelegate.m, in (edited thanks Rog but still not working!)

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator {

if (persistentStoreCoordinator_ != nil) {
    return persistentStoreCoordinator_;
}   

NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]   stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"staff.sqlite"];

NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath]; //new position for the storeUrl!    

// Put down default db if it doesn't already exist
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
    NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"staff" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    if (defaultStorePath) {
        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
    }
}
```

in the

```
    NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"staff.sqlite"];
```

I get the warning

```
NSURL may not respond to '-stringByAppendingPathComponent'
```

I option + click this stringByAppendingPathComponent and get (Symbol not found!!!!)

but in other projects I do option + click in the same and get the definition!!

- so is this warning related to my error??
- how to fix it???

Edit,
included this in my viewDidLoad

> NSLog(@"path= %@", [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]) ;

which gives me in console:

```
path= /Users/mkss9/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/2F364C20-2B87-4ABB-AA3E-FB6F7C15096F/Documents
```

please!, Im getting crazy !!

thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some SDK Version ago (I don't know for sure when they did) apple changed the return type of `applicationDocumentsDirectory` in their project templates.

When you create a new project it looks like this:

```
/**
 Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

in older templates it looked like this:

```
/**
 Returns the path to the application's documents directory.
 */
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}
```

and in between those two it looked like this:

```
/**
 Returns the path to the application's Documents directory.
 */
- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}
```

So you have to be careful, because all the old code that relies on applicationDocumentsDirectory returning a NSString won't work with newer templates.

And you can't just replace the new version with the older version because this would result in a change in your core data methods.

So I would suggest you to write your own method for returning the documents directory. Apple changes their `applicationDocumentsDirectory` quite often.

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine it's because `-applicationDocumentsDirectory` returns an `NSURL *` instead of an `NSString *`.

Comment: I see, but why does this exact code work in my previous projects? even the coredatabooks example from apple uses this> NSString *storePath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"CoreDataBooks.sqlite"];
 what could it be then? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to make sure you `applicationDocumentsDirectory` method is returning a NSString.

Once that's out of the way, the subsequent crash is because you are passing a path and filename that don't exist yet.

So if you move your `NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];` to after the code that checks for an existing file and puts a default one in case it doesn't exist, it should solve your problem.

Comment: hi, did what you suggested but not working yet, please see changes in the edit, thanks

Comment: so I suppose the applicationDocumentsDirectory, is returning the string?? as I see the path in viewDidLoad? for the applicationDocumentsDirectory,, is this right?

Comment: Can you please post your `applicationDocumentsDirectory` interface declaration and implementation, as well as the result of NSLogging `storePath` in your `persistentStoreCoordinator` method? Also if your edit is correct you did not move the `NSURL *storeUrl` method to AFTER your method checks for an existing file in the given path.